# How to add progress bar to the end of GridView when i'm fetching next data

Tags: flutter, gridview, progress-bar

My goal is to add progress bar to the end of GridView when i'm getting next page.I've tried to make progress bar visible when i reach end of the screen then disable it in fetch with isLoading bool but it didn't show anything and i've tried to show progress bar based on itemcount in the Gridview. Here's the code without my attempt:

```
class _PopularGalleryGridState extends State<PopularGalleryGrid> {
      List<Photo> data = new List<Photo>();

      ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
      StreamController<List<Photo>> _photosStreamController =
          StreamController<List<Photo>>.broadcast();

      Future<List<Photo>> _fetchPhotos() async {
        developer.log('fetch photos');
        try {
          final response =
              await http.get(galleryUrl + page.toString() + "&limit=10");
          Map<String, dynamic> decodedJson = json.decode(response.body);
          List photos = decodedJson['data'] as List;
          List<Photo> result =
              (photos.map((photo) => Photo.fromJson(photo))).toList();
          data.addAll(result);
          _photosStreamController.sink.add(data);
        } catch (e) {
          _photosStreamController.sink.addError(e);
        }
      }

      @override
      void initState() {
        data.clear();
        _scrollController.addListener(() {
          if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
              _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
            developer.log('scroll controller');
            page++;
            _fetchPhotos();
          }
        });
        _photosStreamController.onListen = _fetchPhotos;
        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        _scrollController.dispose();
        _photosStreamController?.close();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: StreamBuilder<List<Photo>>(
          stream: _photosStreamController.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            developer.log('builder');
            if (snapshot.hasData || data.isNotEmpty) {
              return _photoGridView(snapshot.data ?? data);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.hasError}");
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ));
      }

      GridView _photoGridView(data) {
        return GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 1.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          ),
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              elevation: 4,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => _navigateToImage(context, data[index].id),
                child: Image.network(
                    ('http://gallery.dev.webant.ru/media/' + data[index].image)),
              ),
            );
          },
          controller: _scrollController,
        );
      }

      void _navigateToImage(BuildContext context, int id) {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SingleImage(imageId: id),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You may have to play around with count and itemBuilder . I hope you get the gist.

```
itemCount: data.length+1,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if(index==data.length) return CircularProgressIndicator();
```

Or you can maintain a loading state flag that resides below the ListView and which triggers on the loading state being true.

Comment: your solution will never work. its crossAxisCount is 2.